# Is there an es6 method to create an array and conditionally push items into it?

Tags: javascript

In my code below I'm creating an array manually and conditionally pushing into it. I was wondering if there exists an es6 method that might be able to clean this up.

```js
let tags = [];
if (member.cohort.inNetwork)) {
    tags.push('Potentially In Network');
}

if (typeof status === 'string') {
    const tag = status
        .toLowerCase()
        .split('_')
        .map((s): string => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase())
        .join(' ');

    tags.push(tag);
}

if (medium === 'In Person') {
    tags.push(medium);
}

return tags;
```

Comment: using custom `Array.prototype`

Comment: What exactly do you think is unclean about this code? I would say it is fine, but alternatives depend on what you are looking for.

Comment: @Bergi My poor choice of words. I was just curious if something exists in es6 that may do achieve something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you were asking specifically about ES6 features, you could use a generator function:

```
function* makeTags() {
    if (member.cohort.inNetwork))
        yield 'Potentially In Network';

    if (typeof status === 'string')
        yield status
            .toLowerCase()
            .split('_')
            .map((s): string => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase())
            .join(' ');

    if (medium === 'In Person')
        yield medium;
}
return Array.from(makeTags());
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no single array method like `.pushIf`. One thing I often end up doing is using an array literal and then filtering out the ones that evaluated false; e.g.,

```
let tags = [
  member.cohort.inNetwork ? 'Potentially In Network' : null,
  typeof status === 'string' ?
    status
      .toLowerCase()
      .split('_')
      .map((s): string => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase())
      .join(' ') :
    null,
  medium === 'In Person' ? medium : null
].filter(a => a !== null);
```

But 1) this only works if there's some value you're sure will never be in you're array (`null` in my example), and 2) is only a readability gain for simple cases. IMO, your original snippet is more readable in this example. But elsewhere, this ends up slightly more readable:

```
let attributes = [];
if (obj.blue)
  array.push('blue');
if (obj.age > 55)
  array.push('old');
if (obj.name[0] === 'Z')
  array.push('unusual name');
```

versus

```
let attributes = [
  obj.blue ? 'blue' : '',
  obj.age > 55 ? 'old' : '',
  obj.name[0] === 'Z' ? 'unusual name' : '',
].filter(a => a);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was mostly just curious about if there are any es6 features, but I think readability would be my biggest priority.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter but definately less readable:

```js
const tags = [
  ...(member.cohort.inNetwork) ? ['Potentially In Network'] : [],
  ...(typeof status === 'string') ? [status.toLowerCase().split('_').map((s): string => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase()).join(' ')] : [],
  ...(medium === 'In Person') ? [medium] : []
];
```

Would prefer your solution over this ... just mention it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I was mostly just curious, but readability would be my biggest concern.